# how to run spark job from intelliJ via yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm running simple spark job

```
val sc = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
 // .set ??? what additional options?      
val inputFile = sc.sequenceFile[LongWritable,String](list_of_directories)
inputFile.count()
```

If I package this code to fat jar and copy it to the cluster machine I can run it with

```
 spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 5 --class com.my.Main test-spark-jobs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

My question is which properties should I set in order to run this job on cluster via the code from not-a-cluster machine?

I have cdh5 with yarn and spark